# How to detect the horizontal and vertical lines of a table and eliminate the noise?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to get the horizontal and vertical lines of the table in an image in order to extract the texts in cells. Here's a picture I use:[image]

I use the code below to extract the vertical and horizontal lines:

```
img = cv2.imread(img_for_box_extraction_path, 0)  # Read the image
(thresh, img_bin) = cv2.threshold(img, 200, 255,
                                  cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)  # Thresholding the image
img_bin = 255-img_bin  # Invert the image
cv2.imwrite("Image_bin_2.jpg",img_bin)

# Defining a kernel length
kernel_length = np.array(img).shape[1]//140

# A verticle kernel of (1 X kernel_length), which will detect all the verticle lines from the image.
verticle_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, kernel_length))

# A horizontal kernel of (kernel_length X 1), which will help to detect all the horizontal line from the image.
hori_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (kernel_length, 1))

# A kernel of (3 X 3) ones.
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))

# Morphological operation to detect verticle lines from an image
img_temp1 = cv2.erode(img_bin, verticle_kernel, iterations=3)
verticle_lines_img = cv2.dilate(img_temp1, verticle_kernel, iterations=3)
cv2.imwrite("verticle_lines_2.jpg",verticle_lines_img)

# Morphological operation to detect horizontal lines from an image
img_temp2 = cv2.erode(img_bin, hori_kernel, iterations=3)
horizontal_lines_img = cv2.dilate(img_temp2, hori_kernel, iterations=3)
cv2.imwrite("horizontal_lines_2.jpg",horizontal_lines_img)
```

The pictures below are the horizontal lines and vertical lines:
[image: horizontal lines]
[image: vertical lines]

I use the code below to add two image together

```
# Weighting parameters, this will decide the quantity of an image to be added to make a new image.
alpha = 0.5
beta = 1.0 - alpha

# This function helps to add two image with specific weight parameter to get a third image as summation of two image.
img_final_bin = cv2.addWeighted(verticle_lines_img, alpha, horizontal_lines_img, beta, 0.0)
img_final_bin = cv2.erode(~img_final_bin, kernel, iterations=2)
(thresh, img_final_bin) = cv2.threshold(img_final_bin, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# For Debugging
# Enable this line to see verticle and horizontal lines in the image which is used to find boxes
cv2.imwrite("img_final_bin_2.jpg",img_final_bin)
```

However, I get a picture like this:
[image: Summation Result]
How do I remove the noise and get a better result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesnt houghline work fine?

Comment: Increase the length of the kernels so that they are longer than the width and height of the text.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a simple method:

Binary image

[image]

Detected horizontal

[image]

Detected vertical

[image]

Combined masks

[image]

Lines to be removed in green

[image]

Result

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Detect horizontal lines
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (50,1))
horizontal_mask = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=1)

# Detect vertical lines
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,50))
vertical_mask = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=1)

# Combine masks and remove lines
table_mask = cv2.bitwise_or(horizontal_mask, vertical_mask)
image[np.where(table_mask==255)] = [255,255,255]

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('horizontal_mask', horizontal_mask)
cv2.imshow('vertical_mask', vertical_mask)
cv2.imshow('table_mask', table_mask)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. How would i go about just extracting the vertical masks into separate images. i.e in your example I'd like to have 4 separate images one for each column. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: is their any method to write this information into word document ?

Comment: @user1014691 `cv2.findContours`, iterate through each and save each contour with `cv2.imwrite`

Comment: @SybghatallahMarwat Yes once you have the processed and extracted contour, you perform OCR. Take a look through my past answers for an example. You should open a new question for this

Answer (score 1):

Try [reduce](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#reduce) with CV_REDUCE_AVG flag along horizontal for your first binary image and then anlong vertical direction for your second one. Threshols histograms you'll get. And use them to filter your lines.

As an alternative, you can try hough lines detector and filter lines by length and algle.