# Extracting vertical masks into separate images

Tags: python, opencv

I'm fairly new to opencv, I am essentially trying to extract a table from an image, and I need to be able to get the columns seperately,

I have come across this code here [How to detect the horizontal and vertical lines of a table and eliminate the noise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60521925/how-to-detect-the-horizontal-and-vertical-lines-of-a-table-and-eliminate-the-noi)

It almost accomplishes that I need in terms of segmenting the table vertically. The issue is that I need those separate segments saved as separate images. Is there way to go about doing that?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('x.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Detect vertical lines
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,50))
vertical_mask = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=1)

# Combine masks and remove lines
table_mask = cv2.bitwise_or(0,vertical_mask)
image[np.where(table_mask==255)] = [255,255,255]

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The code above removes the vertical lines, however I need those vertical images in separate files.

Comment: every image in `cv2` is  `numpy.array` and you can get part of array `image[row_start:row_end, col_start:col_end ]` and save it with `cv2.imwrite()`

Comment: I see, thanks for that. How would I go about getting the starting and ending rows and columns of the vertical mask?

Comment: check what you have in `image[np.where(table_mask==255)]` - ie. `cv2.imshow('image',  image[np.where(table_mask==255)] )`. If it is part which you want to save then `cv2.imwrite( "output.png", image[np.where(table_mask==255)] )`